# How to upgrade an installed package under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, package-management, apt-get

Based on https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/apt-get.html

The way to upgrade packages is to:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, I simply just want to upgrade one software for example ipython-notebook.
I have used the following command to install this package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook
```

How do I just upgrade one package (e.g., `ipython-notebook`)?

Comment: Install as with other answers or the upgrade-only option: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/upgrade-a-single-package-with-apt-get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply invoke:

```
sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook
```

If the package is already installed in an older version, it is updated.

#### Note

1. To reinstall an already installed package you can also invoke:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall PackageName
   ```
2. Most likely you want to refer to the current server guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/apt-get.html

#### Additional question: *"Does this reset config files?"*

- If you reconfigured a `debconf` configured configuration file by hand - your changes may be overwritten.
- If you changed a "manual" maintained configuration file, it shouldn`t be touched by the update

Maybe you have also a look at [How to check for modified config files on a Debian system?](https://serverfault.com/questions/90400/how-to-check-for-modified-config-files-on-a-debian-system)

Comment: Does that reset config files and the like?

Comment: @Kruug see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Re-run `sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook`.  Apt will check to see if the package is installed before calling the install, it will see that the package is installed, and upgrade if necessary.